# req.session losses its userId parameterthat I set in /login . When I try to access req.session again from /check-auth it doesn't contain userId

Tags: javascript, mongodb, session, server

So when I set req.session.user in /login, console.log() shows that req.session contains userId however when I try to access req.session in /check-auth I can't access the session.

```
const express = require("express");
const session = require("express-session");
const MongoStore = require("connect-mongo");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const cors = require("cors");

const users = require("./models/user");

const app = express();
const port = 8000;
const saltRounds = 10;

const mongoDB = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/project]";
mongoose
    .connect(mongoDB, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
    .then(() => console.log("Connected to database"))
    .catch((error) => console.error("Error connecting to database:", error));
const db = mongoose.connection;

db.on("error", console.error.bind(console, "MongoDB connection error:"));

db.on("connected", function () {
    console.log("Connected to database");
});

app.use(
    session({
        secret: "Super secret secret",
        cookie: {
            maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
            domain: "localhost",
            secure: false,
            httpOnly: true,
        },
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: false,
        store: MongoStore.create({
            mongoUrl: "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/project",
        }),
    })
);

app.use(
    cors({
        origin: "http://localhost:3000",
        methods: ["POST", "PUT", "GET", "OPTIONS", "HEAD"],
        credentials: true,
    })
);

app.use(express.json());

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`);
});

process.on("SIGINT", () => {
    console.log("Server closed. Database instance disconnected");
    server.close(() => {
        db.close(() => {
            process.exit(0);
        });
    });
});

app.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        let { username, password } = req.body;
        let user = await users.findOne({ username: username });

        if (user && (await bcrypt.compare(password, user.passwordHash))) {
            req.session.userId = user._id;
            req.session.save();
            console.log("Session:", req.session);
            res.status(200).send("Login successful!");
        } else {
            res.status(401).json({ error: "Invalid credentials" });
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Internal server error", error.message);
        res.status(500).json("Internal server error");
    }
});

app.get("/check-auth", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        console.log("Session in check-auth:", req.session);
        console.log("Session User:", req.session.userId);
        if (req.session && req.session.userId) {
            let user = await users.findById(req.session.userId);
            console.log("User Details:", user);
            if (user) {
                res.status(200).json({ authenticated: true, user });
            } else {
                res.status(401).json({ authenticated: false });
            }
        } else {
            res.status(200).json({ authenticated: false });
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error checking authentication: ", error);
        res.status(500).json({
            authenticated: false,
            error: "Internal server error",
        });
    }
});
```

I mean I don't really know what else to try, I am very new to backend web development., i want to check if a session already exists and get user information using it, however req.session doesn't seem to keep the saved parameters.